# Tool which adds exception info or checks this info to doxygen-like comments?

Tags: c++, exception

I have been thinking about this for really long time (in fact, years) and searching best way to handle exceptions in C++. And so I thought of tool, which could help me and so I would like to ask if this tool exists (I couldn't Google it).

This tool would parse C++ source code (both headers and sources) and filled doxygen-like comments with exception info (preferably extending comments I already wrote about method itself). For each method exception list would be generated from code - from each time there is "throw SomeException;" command, from list of called functions (beware of recursion) and from known commands possible throwing exceptions (currently, I can fink only of operator new). So I could track all exceptions and see if I forget to manage exception from other modules and see if there is accidental possibility of throwing exception from destructor (which prohibited AFAIK).

Or I could use similar tool which wouldn't automatically fill doxygen comments, but at least warn me about not commented ones. Similarly like when I run doxygen documentation generator, I forget comment one input variable and the generator warns me about this.

So, is there such tool? And if not, is there very simple-to-use library parsing C++ code so I could easily implement it for myself?

Example:

```
//// Example.h ////

/**
  * Does almost nothing.
  */
void foo1();

/**
  * Generates some error.
  */
void foo2();

//// Example.cpp ////

#include "Example.h"

void foo1()
{
    foo2();
}

void foo2()
{
    throw MyException();
}
```

This would:

1. Add "@throw MyException" line to foo1() comment.
2. Give warning: "foo1() in file ... line ...: throws MyException, but not in comment!"

I know that C++ language provides possibility of specification of possibly thrown exceptions, problem is that this is not checked in compile time, but in runtime. And I need to handle this case (std::unexpected if I remember correctly).

It's not problem if this tool is needed to be run manually, like doxygen, and not at every time I compile.

Comment: And what if your function calls a function in some library for which you don't have the source code?

Comment: I was thinking if someone asks this question or not and if I should answer it in advance XD. In this case, it could be many ways: when used, the tool could detect some "unknown" (not name of class) exception, "all" exceptions or just require catch(...) block. The last one would be solution of previous cases too and IMHO it's good solution while using the library without access to code, there can be some unexpected exception at the end.

Comment: Also, the tool could provide settings for this case enabling to prepare list of exceptions which would automatically apply to all functions in some directory and/or (header) file. This would allow better exception tracking but what I wrote earlier would be sufficient enough ... at least for me :3.

Also, for such library, there are 2 possibilities: known documented exceptions - then this info could be parsed and added, or this info isn't documented and the tool would have to assume "any" (again, not real class) exception anyway.